# Field not visible in Visual Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual

I'm working on a visual flow and there are three fields (a picklist, and two string fields) that are being read as blank values. I've checked the field security and am not sure why these fields are being recognized as blank. I put a screen in my flow to write the values of those fields onto for troubleshooting and they're coming up blank even though when I look into Salesforce these fields hold values. I'm storing them in an SObjectVariable but for some reason they're not available. Other values that I stored in the same way are visible just fine. Would appreciate any suggestions as to what I might be able to look for. Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting the values in an SObjectVariable?

Comment: I have a create record earlier in the process and have created an SObjectVariable where I'm storing the values

Comment: Hmm. The only time I ever use an SObjectVariable is as a loop variable when going through a loop. If the values are coming from a screen then make sure to have them actually assign to variables in an assignment or on lookup. Attaching a screenshot of the flow might help.